# Facebook javascript sdk api share a link and have an image of size 154 on the wall

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to share a link to facebook and have an image on the wall of bigger size. I share a link as follows:

```
    FB.ui(
      {
        method : 'feed',
        name: 'the name whatever',
        caption: 'some caption',
        description: 'description',
        link: 'http://mysite.com/some_page',
        picture: photo_url
      },
      function (response) { ... }
    );
```

The picture is bigger then 154x154, i tried size 180x180 (i read somewhere in the docs it's required 180x180), but it ends up of size 90x90 on the wall anyway :(.

If i remove the picture parameter the image will be taken of the og:image meta tag, but it is still 90x90 pixels! If i post the link myself i can see it grabs the correct size - so when i post to wall myself it posts image of size 154x154, but how can i do the same to post it via the api facebook provides?

Tried it this way as well - works the same, please help :(

```
    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post',
      {
        link : 'http://whatever_mysite.com/some_page',
        picture : photo_url
      },
      function (response) { ... }
    );
```

This is when posted manually, a direct link to a site(image taken off the meta tags):
[image]

This is when shared via api(original: http://www.dandybooksellers.com/acatalog/TheoryTest.jpg ):
[image]

When no "picture" argument is provided it posts the "TEST IMAGE" from meta tags, but still with the size 90x90

Answer (score 1):

The URL of a picture attached to this post. The picture must be at least 50px by 50px (though minimum 200px by 200px is preferred) and have a maximum aspect ratio of 3:1

For more detail, please refer: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: thank you for you reply, i tried an image of size exactly 200x200, but it still sizes it to 90x90 when posted :( The image i will use will have it's aspect ratio 1:1 and i need it to be of size 154x154 on facebook